# The use of the phrasal verb "pay off" in context

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Tell me please if it is apt to use the phrasal verb in the following conext.

> The tablet was expensive, but I don't regret buying it, because it is **paying off**.

What I mean is that the tablet proved to be very useful and it benefits me. By the pronoun *it* I am referring to the tablet, not to the action of buying. If I referred to buying, would the pronoun *this* be more appropriate? For example:

> The tablet was expensive, but I don't regret buying it, because **this** is paying off.

Comment: Hello, Dmytro. Are you asking about the use in general of 'paying off' (in which case the question may be closed because it shows no signs of research), or the validity of using 'it' with two different referents (the tablet, and (notionally) buying the tablet) , the _it_'s being so close together? 'Misplaced modifiers' is a related topic and posts addressing this may also cover 'non-corresponding pronouns'. In speech, the 'it' in "because it's paying off" (note the contraction) would be under-emphasised, and this would differentiate the _it_'s so much that IMHO few ...

Comment: people would think 'possibly ungrammatical'. 'This' sounds over-formal, highfalutin,  in conversation: IMHO approaching 'error' status more closely. "The tablet was expensive, but I don't regret buying it - it's really paying off" probably pushes the conflicting-_it_ issue further into the background, but I'd use "The tablet was expensive, but I don't regret buying it. Money well spent" (which _really_ hides the _it_).

Comment: Do the sentences sound natural?

Comment: In conversation? My first suggestion sounds more natural to my (aging British) ears, but "The tablet was expensive, but I don't regret buying it, because it's paying off" sounds reasonable (though IMHO a 'really' makes it more natural-sounding). [Woops. Forgot to convert a hyphen above to a dash in time. And another hyphen sneaked in.]

Comment: I am sorry, but what does IMHO stands for?

Comment: It's a hedge, showing that I'm giving what is my opinion rather than accredited fact (though I wouldn't give it if I didn't consider it very reasonable). 'In my honest/humble  opinion.' Perhaps best thought of as 'others may disagree, and have conflicting views; they are obviously free to give these, provided they too either concede and state the possibility of their interpretation being challengeable, or supply incontrovertible proof of validity'.

Comment: I just answered [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/504215/if-variety-is-a-singular-collective-noun-can-i-refer-to-it-with-it/504240#504240) question, which has the same issue with pronoun use. As there, here I would not personally interpret *it* as standing for the tablet, but for the action of buying it. It's somewhat unidiomatic to say that an object *itself* is paying off.  (It is, however, ambiguous.) If you're concerned with ambiguity, rephrase the sentence and drop the pronoun.

Comment: The implied subject of *paying off* is the *investment in a tablet*.  If this investment pays off, that means that you are receiving benefits from having made the investment. // *It* works better than *this*.

Comment: It seems slightly ambiguous because "paying off" can refer to clearing a debt (including where you've taken out a loan to buy something) as well as having the less literal sense intended. So is the tablet literally being paid off, or only metaphorically?

Answer (score 1):

**pay off**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pay+off) a phrasal verb

> 2. To result in profit or advantage; to succeed

As in:

X is/are **paying off**.

and your sentence:

*The tablet was expensive, but it's **paying off**.*

Here, you can drop the extra pronoun.

Answer (score -1):

> If I referred to buying, would the pronoun *this* be more appropriate?

Yes, it would, because *this* (as opposed to *that*) refers to the syntactically-closer* of the two potential antecedents.

*"buying" is three words away from the pronoun, whereas "tablet" is ten words distant

Comment: (1) It's not guaranteed that "this" will refer to the closest antecedent syntactically - spatial distance is relevant too. (2) In the original example, "it" could refer to "tablet" or "buying"; there is little difference in meaning. (3) Using "this" in this example comes across as rather clumsy wording.