# If "variety" is a singular collective noun, can I refer to it with "it"?

Tags: grammatical-number, collective-nouns

In this sentence I used *it* to refer to *a variety* mentioned a few words earlier, because I consider *variety* to be a collective noun which can be referred to in the singular. However, I'm not certain that the result actually reads that way: is *it* in my sentence actually referring unambiguously to the *variety*?

> Shop vendors should include **a variety** of imported products because **it** solidifies the bond between countries and offers wide range of choice to customers.

Comment: Hello, prog94. When you think about it, isn't it the shopkeepers' 'includ[ing] a variety of imported products' (and the fact that various exporters are obviously aware of this), rather than the actual cans, boxes, wedges, whatever, that give rise to a stronger relationship? 'It' refers to the nearest _sensible/logical_ referent, here the shopkeepers' _'including' [/buying and stocking] a plethora of imported goods_. Perhaps 'this' (hinting at 'this practice') is a better choice.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not unambiguous. ***It*** can be referring to either *a variety* or to *shop vendors including a variety*.

(My personal parsing would be to interpret it as referring to the action rather than to the noun, but that's subjective.)

To rephrase it to make it unambiguous, you have to drop the pronoun.

Here are some possibilities:

> 1. Shop vendors should include <sup>a variety of imported products</sup> because ***such a variety*** solidifies the bond between countries and offers ***a*** wide range of choice to customers.
> 2. Shop vendors should <sup>include a variety of imported products</sup> because ***doing so*** solidifies the bond between countries and offers ***a*** wide range of choice to customers.

---

Note that there is also a third variation of this sentence, one in which the use of *it* would have been not just ambiguous but inappropriate:

> 3. Shop vendors should include a variety of <sup>imported products</sup> because ***these products solidify*** the bond between countries and ***offer a*** wide range of choice to customers.